# Javascript: fetch text and cut off

Tags: javascript, jquery

for the following html structure i want to extract `1 - 10 of 12` and keep only the last two characters of it, i.e. `12`. How can I do this? I don't understand how to access elements or text without identifier.

```
<div class="paging-wrapper" xpath="1">
   <div class="paging-label">
      <!----><!----> 1 - 10 of  12 <!----><span>Text</span>
   </div>
```

I first tried to output the text at all, but it only finds the text in the `<span>` and not the characters I actually want.

```
cy.xpath("//div[@class='paging-wrapper']//div[@class='paging-label']").then(($pageCounter) => {
    const pageCount = $pageCounter.text()
    cy.log(pageCount)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the span for the `paging-label` div and then just get the text for that div and slice the last 2 elements

```
$(".paging-label").find("span").remove()
$(".paging-label").text().trim().slice(-2) // Return 12
```

That should return 12 for the example that you mentioned

You can play around removing the span, save it in a variable, getting the value that you need, and then adding the span again to the `paging-label` div in case that you needed